# MySQL Update Value of column Based on DATE

Tags: mysql, date

I have a database problem with MySQL
I created a **database** with a table **CustomerInfo** 
[image]

Every year i want to update kilometers plus 1000

For example the row 6 today should be updated to 
7000 kilometers from 6000 and the date from 2013-08-06 to 2014-08-06

```
update database.CustomerInfo 
set Kilometers = Kilometers + 1000
where date_add(Date, interval 1 year) = curdate();
```

This code isn't correct and the date update is missing

If i run query

```
select * from database.customerinfo where date_add(Date, interval 1 year) = curdate();
```

returns row 6

thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date update is missing since you are not updating the date

```
update database.CustomerInfo 
set Kilometers = Kilometers + 1000, Date = curdate()
where date_add(Date, interval 1 year) = curdate();
```

Comment: MySQL returns Error Code when i try it 
i think 
`where date_add(Date, interval 1 year) = curdate();`

isn't correct

Comment: no the `date_add()` is correct, could you get the exact error you are getting ?

Comment: Ok i solved it with this `where idCustomerInfo >= 1 and date_add(Date, interval 1 year) = curdate(); `